# Installing postfix from centosplus repository "Could not resolve host: mirrors.linode.com; Unknown error"

Tags: centos, yum, repository

I am follwing a [tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mariadb-on-centos-7) on installing Postfix with MariaDB support. Since the default `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` repo doesn't support Postfix with MariaDB, I modified the file with `exclude=postfix` and `enabled=1` lines

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
exclude=postfix

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
exclude=postfix

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
baseurl=http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1
```

I run `yum --enablerepo=centosplus install postfix`, but got an error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.linode.com; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=centosplus&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"
    http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/7/centosplus/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.linode.com; Unknown error"
    Trying other mirror.


failure: repodata/repomd.xml from centosplus: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirrors.linode.com/centos/7/centosplus/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.linode.com; Unknown error"
```

Any idea what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: set `enable=0` on `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf` and comment the `mirrorlist=http:/....` then try again

Comment: Thanks for stopping by, but it doesn't work

Comment: comment all `mirrorlsit`

Comment: doesn't help either. Can you replicate the problem on your machine or does it exist only on mine?

Comment: See [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/package-mirrors) maybe you need to modify the `baseurl`

Comment: Actually, my default configuration had baseUrl uncommented and set to what this article suggests

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Nothing. Every line is commented out.

Comment: add the following line to your `/etc/resolv.conf` : `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4 nameserver 127.0.0.1` . Undo all changes montionned on my olders comments.

Comment: Oh dammit, I missed the first line. It states: search mydamainnamehere.mytldhere. will try the above mentioned.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Be sure to add you answer  below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Could not resolve host: mirrors.linode.com; Unknown error"

Edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` by adding the following line:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4 nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Adding Google DNS nameservers on the top of your `resolv.conf` will give  `yum` a valid DNS servers to resolve IP addresses and hosts

Comment: Thanks. Can you add why can I use yum for other repos, but for centosplus I need to use Googles DNS servers?